# What plants will help with our midge and mosquito problem?

Tags: flowers, pest-control, mosquito

We've been here since April 2017 and after a brief respite, swarms of midges are already starting to form at the start of February.
We're in North East England near a river, nestled amongst woodland, and last summer both midges and mosquitos were a real issue... They seem particularly potent as even those not normally bothered got nasty bites, I had seeping wounds!

In my part of the world, what plants would be a good option to help?

Comment: Do you know where they are breeding?

Comment: I assume around the river... Not much I can do about that?

Comment: Well, they won't be in the river so there must be pools of standing water elsewhere.  If you can find those you can treat them with mosquito dunks.

Comment: The range of mosquitoes is a few hundred metres, so I'd need to treat up to a square kilometre of land that didn't belong to me. I don't think prevention is feasible?

Comment: Talk to your neighbours who must also want the problem treated.

Comment: That said I never heard of this product... Thanks for the tip

Comment: I live in the country, I have no neighbours!

Comment: Mosquito dunks are difficult to get in the UK, pretty expensive, and are intended for use in ornamental ponds rather than in the wider environment.. Unfortunately, where you live, a midge problem is quite normal - its even worse in Scotland, though  don't suppose that's much comfort to you. And the mosquitoes/midges we get here don't carry malaria and other diseases as they do elsewhere, which is why there's never been much on the market to deal with what's essentially an irritating, intractable, but not health threatening problem.